# React, problem with my Todo list app, my search engine only finds notes on the page I'm on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

Hello I am making an application to practice React, my notes app has a pagination which works perfectly, the problem is in the search engine, which only looks for notes from the page I'm on, for example, if I'm on page 2 and I look for a note on page 2, it shows it, however if the note is on a different page, it doesn't show it, it doesn't find it.

I know where the problem is but I'm not sure how to solve it, I'm a bit new to React and I was asking for your help.

I was able to do my pagination with the package `react-paginate` here is the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

My code:

Component `App.js`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import './App.css';
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";

const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); 

  const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true); //eslint-disable-line
  useEffect(() => {
    const saveNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-data'));
    if (saveNotes){
      setNotes(saveNotes);
    }
    
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes-data', JSON.stringify(notes))
  },[notes])

  const addNote = (inputText, text) => { 
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title: inputText,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleString()
      
    }
    const newNotes = [newNote, ...notes];
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }
  const deleteNote = (id) => {
    var response = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
    if (response){
      const notesUpdated = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id)
      setNotes(notesUpdated);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>
      <div className="container">
        <Header 
          handleToggleTheme={setDarkMode}
        />
        <Search 
          handleSearchNote={setSearchText}
          setShowNote={setShowNote}
        />
        <Pagination 
          data={notes} 
          handleAddNote={addNote}
          handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
          searchText={searchText}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Component `Pagination.js`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import '../styles/Pagination.css';
import NoteList from './NoteList';
import { MdSkipPrevious, MdSkipNext } from 'react-icons/md';


const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { data, searchText, handleAddNote, handleDeleteNote } = props;
    
  // We start with an empty list of items.
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]);
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  // Here we use item offsets; we could also use page offsets
  // following the API or data you're working with.
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
  const itemsPerPage = 9;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch items from another resources.
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    console.log(`Loading items from ${itemOffset} to ${endOffset}`);
    setCurrentItems(data.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage));
  }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage, data]);

  // Invoke when user click to request another page.
  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
  const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % data.length;
    console.log(
    `User requested page number ${event.selected}, which is offset ${newOffset}`
    );
    setItemOffset(newOffset);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <NoteList 
       notes={currentItems.filter((noteText) => 
          noteText.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        )}
        handleAddNote={handleAddNote}
        handleDeleteNote={handleDeleteNote}
      />
      <div className="pagination-wrapper">

      <ReactPaginate
        breakLabel="..."
        nextLabel={<MdSkipNext 
          className='icons'
        />}
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        previousLabel={<MdSkipPrevious 
          className='icons'
        />}
        renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
        containerClassName="pagination"
        pageLinkClassName="page-num"
        previousLinkClassName="page-num"
        nextLinkClassName="page-num"
        activeLinkClassName="activee boxx"
      />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Pagination;
```

Component `NoteList.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Note from './Note'
import '../styles/NoteList.css'
import AddNote from './AddNote'

const NoteList = ({ notes, handleAddNote, handleDeleteNote }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="add-notes-wrapper">
        <AddNote 
          handleAddNote={handleAddNote}     
        />
      </div>
      <div className='notes-list'>
        {notes.map((note => 
          <Note 
            key={note.id}
            id={note.id}
            title={note.title}
            text={note.text}
            date={note.date}
            handleDeleteNote={handleDeleteNote}
         />
        ))}     
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default NoteList;
```

Component `Search.js`

```
//import React, { useState } from 'react'
import {MdSearch, MdAdd} from 'react-icons/md'
import '../styles/Search.css'


const Search = ({ handleSearchNote, setShowNote }) => {
  const handleShowAddNote = () => {
    if (setShowNote){ 
      let addNote = document.querySelector('.new');
      addNote.classList.add('wobble-horizontal-top')
      addNote.style.display='flex';
      document.querySelector('.notes-list').style.display='none';
      document.querySelector('.pagination').style.display='none';
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='search'>
      <div className="input-wrapper">
        <MdSearch 
          className='icon search-icon'
        /> 
        <input 
          type="text" 
          placeholder='What note are you looking for?'
          onChange={(event) => handleSearchNote(event.target.value) }
        />
      </div>
      <div className="btn-wrapper-search">
        <button 
          className='btn-addNote'
          onClick={handleShowAddNote}>
          Nueva Nota
        </button>
        <MdAdd 
          className='icon add-icon'
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Search
```

**The problem is in the component** `Pagination.js` because I'm filtering the notes on each page with the `currentItems` variable, if I did it with the `data` variable it would work, but then it would show all the notes, and I don't want that, I currently want to show 9 notes per page.

greetings and thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

@Newbie I'm doing what you said, but I don't know if you mean this, in my `Pagination.js` component I did:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const filterNotes=data.filter((noteText) => 
      noteText.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
    )
    setItemOffset(0);
  }, [data, searchText])
```

It doesn't work, do I have to pass a prop to my components additionally?
greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested to you, search all the notes with `searchText` in your App.js and pass the results into the Pagination component and it will solve your problem.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-thompson-xugs0c

**Edit**

All changes are as per what we talked about in the email.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/green-fast-3k76wx

Comment: Hello again Nisharg, it doesn't work for me but I will investigate it, although I have had a serious problem, when I added your code somehow the notes that I already had stored in my localStorage, have been deleted all, (they were test notes, they were not important, but it's good to know what happened to take it into consideration for future) Greetings ^^

Comment: Take a backup of important things before applying any code from the SO and about the problem, it is working fine you can check in the codesandbox. if you are not able to solve the problem, please come up with the codesandbox link of your code and I will try to solve the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I have sent you an email Nisharg, thanks ^^

Comment: Replied you in mail :)

Comment: Completed @JuanJesús, please check

Answer (score 0):

Search and pagination do not play well together, one of the common solutions is to jump to page 1 each time the filter term changes.

So use an `useEffect` on `searchText` to filter `data` and reset `itemOffset` to 0, then redo pagination as if the data changed.

The user will jump to page 1 at each keystroke of the search, then he can navigate pages (if there are more than one). This will lead to a less confusing UX.

Comment: Hey @Newbie I made an edit with what you wrote, can you check it? It doesn't work for me. Thanks